# помогите перевести с паскаля на C++

Tags: c++, pascal

```
program Pr424;
var
s, t : real;
r : real;
function F(a, b, c : real) : real;
begin
result := (2 * a - b - sin(c)) / (5 + abs(c));
end;
begin
readln(s ,t);
r := F(t, -2*s, 1.17) + F(2.2, t, s - t);
writeln(r:10:5);
readln;
 end.
```

Comment: Прочитайте уже какие-нибудь учебники

Comment: Ожидаем третью часть бессмертного блокбастера «Помогите перевести с паскаля на С++». Только на ru.SO!

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, ожидание можно скрасить спин-оффом «[Перевод с C++ на C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/835657/208074)».

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

double F(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return (2 * a - b - sin(c)) / (5 + abs(c));
}

int main()
{
    double r, s, t;
    cin >> s;
    cin >> t;
    r = F(t, -2*s, 1.17) + F(2.2, t, s - t);
    printf("%10.5f", r);
    return 0;
}
```